# GridView Row FindControl(x) Text is blank

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView where I want to hide some of the rows when the price is 0.  When I try to check the value I get a blank string for all rows.

Markup: non relevant rows have been removed for readability.  getProductInfo and getPrice are lookup functions receiving and returning strings

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvRebuild" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="gvRebuild_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ... />
        <asp:TemplateField ... />
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-Width="12%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="price" ><%# getPrice(getProductInfo(Eval("fieldName")))%></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ... />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub gvRebuild_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Dim p As Label = e.Row.FindControl("price")
    If p IsNot Nothing Then
        Debug.Print(String.Format("*{0}*", p.Text))
        If p.Text = "$0.00" Then
            e.Row.Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The debug statement is confirming that all values found in the "price" control are blank.  I have also confirmed via debugger that the getPrice function is returning the correct value and firing before the RowDataBound event handler for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the RowType. The first row will be the header row. The header row does not contain the TextBox, hence the NULL error.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //use findcontrol here
    }
}
```

VB

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        'use findcontrol here
    End If
End Sub
```

Update

I see what you mean now. It is the value that is NULL not the control itself.
I did some testing and it turns out that if you use your method it does not work. But change it to this and it will.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="price" Text='<%# getPrice(getProductInfo(Eval("fieldName"))) %>'></asp:Label>
```

It seems that the binding of data inside the tag is done after the row or gridview has completed, but the Text property is set right away.

Comment: This was being accounted for when checking If p IsNot Nothing.  I tried your solution anyway but it made no change to my results.